# React Router in Laravel

Tags: reactjs, laravel

I'm trying to build a Laravel project using ReactJS. I've done show the data on table. However, when I add some links like **Create, Edit, Delete...** , it occurred some errors:

```
- Failed context type: The context `router` is marked as required in `Link`, but its value is `undefined`.
- Uncaught Error: You should not use `Link` outside a `Router`
```

So:

1. I created RoutePath.js to create Routes only but i dont know how to import them into Example.js
2. When add page, edit page...is clicked, it redirects to blank page, not below the homepage. However, It seems that the add page will be below the homepage

Im new so please help me. Thank you. Here's my code:

Example.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import axios from 'axios';
import {Link} from "react-router-dom";
import CreatePost from './CreatePost';
import RoutePath from '../routes/RoutePath';

...

postRow(p){
        return (
            <tr key = {p.id}>
                <td>{p.title}</td>
                <td>{p.description}</td>
                <td><Link to='/edit'></Link></td>
                <td><Link to='/delete'></Link></td>
            </tr>
        )
    }

    render() {
        const posts = this.state.posts.map(post => this.postRow(post));
        return (
                <div>
                    <table border="1">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Title</th>
                            <th>Description</th>
                            <th></th>
                            <th></th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        { posts }
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <div>
                        <Link to='/add-post'>Add</Link>
                    </div>
                </div>

        );
    }
}
ReactDOM.render(
    <Example />
    , document.getElementById('homepage')
);
```

RoutePath.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { Route, BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import CreatePost from '../components/CreatePost';
import Example from '../components/Example';

export default class RoutePath extends Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <BrowserRouter>
                    <div>
                        <Route exact path='/' component={Example}/>
                        <Route path='/add-post' component={CreatePost}/>
                        <Route path='/edit' component={Edit}/>
                    </div>
            </BrowserRouter>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: You're trying to render `<Example />` directly in `Example.js` you should let it get rendered from `RoutePath` instead since that's wrapped in a Router

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In `RoutePath`, you need to import `Switch` from
   `'react-router-dom'` at first.
2. Then you shouldn't render in `Example`, otherwise you should render on `RoutePath`
3. You need to redirect the JS app to `RoutePath` in your `app.js`.

### app.js

```
require('./homeComponents/RoutePath');
```

### RoutePath.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Route, BrowserRouter, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import CreatePost from '../components/CreatePost';
import Example from '../components/Example';

export default class RoutePath extends Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <BrowserRouter>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route exact path='/' component={Example}/>
                        <Route path='/add-post' component={CreatePost}/>
                        <Route path='/edit' component={Edit}/>
                    </Switch>
            </BrowserRouter>
        )
    }
}
ReactDOM.render(
    <RoutePath />
    , document.getElementById('homepage')
);
```

### Example.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import {Link} from "react-router-dom";
import CreatePost from './CreatePost';
import RoutePath from '../routes/RoutePath';

postRow(p){
        return (
            <tr key = {p.id}>
                <td>{p.title}</td>
                <td>{p.description}</td>
                <td><Link to='/edit'></Link></td>
                <td><Link to='/delete'></Link></td>
            </tr>
        )
    }

    render() {
        const posts = this.state.posts.map(post => this.postRow(post));
        return (
                <div>
                    <table border="1">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Title</th>
                            <th>Description</th>
                            <th></th>
                            <th></th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        { posts }
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <div>
                        <Link to='/add-post'>Add</Link>
                    </div>
                </div>

        );
    }
}
```

So basically the flow is here:

1. The webpack tries to compile the `app.js` to `/public/js` in default.
2. The `app.js` requires `RoutePath` that contains all of your routing stuff.
3. The `RoutePath` was trying to render all of your component you have in root (`'/'`), and it render `Example`
4. The component has been rendered to `'homepage'` id in your blade.

Comment: I see. Thank you so much!

Comment: Can I ask one more question? When I add a post and click 'Add' button, I want it redirect automatically to Homepage or any page that I want to, so how can I do it? I searched in the Internet and found 'browserHistory' from 'react-router' but it seems like it does not exist because of new version of React

Comment: If you render a <Redirect/> object when you need to redirect it should work.

Answer (score 6):

This works for me... My single view for my Single-Page-App is `home.blade.php` and I am using `BrowserRouter` in my `App.js`

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('home');
});

Route::get('/{route}',function(){
    return view('home');
});
```

This will allow you to go to http://localhost/ and get the homepage of the app or http://localhost/about-us and get the 'about-us' route.

This is a better method than using HashRouter which would look a little uglier: http://localhost/#/about-us

Answer (score 0):

To add on to what @manley13 suggested. You can also do it in one `get` call:

```
Route::get('/{route?}',function(){
    return view('home');
});
```

The `?` makes the `route` optional.